# Qt 5 YandexMapKit QtQuick

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, yandexmapkit

Мне необходимо создать приложение, где на карте в радиусе 1 км будут отображаться проходящие мероприятия.

Для этого я выбрал Yandex, т.к. у них проще и быстрее всего получить ключ, но вот как подключить библиотеки яндекса к Qt я не знаю.

В итоге и появился вопрос: как подключить библиотеки *YandexMapKit* в *Qt5*?

Comment: Вы можете добавлять важную информацию в вопрос, воспользовавшись ссылкой [edit] под постом.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `QtWebKit` (или `QtWebEngine` для Qt5.5) и загружайте карты как обычный HTML в `QWebView` виджете.