# QML + YandexMapKit

Tags: qt, yandex-maps-api, qml, yandexmapkit

Мне нужна карта яндекса, для выставления меток. Насколько я понял, мне нужно воспользоваться Yandex Map Kit.

Вопрос: как подключить YandexMapKit в QML?

P.S. Знаю о похожем вопросе [Qt 5 YandexMapKit QtQuick](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457135/qt-5-yandexmapkit-qtquick), но это был 2015 год, возможно появился более удобный способ.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас нет отдельной сборки MapKit для Qt приложений.
MapKit доступен только для Android из Java и Swift/Obj-C на iOS.

В этом случае можно попытаться использовать веб API карт и отображать его в WebView.